# Error in image uploading and renaming in php

Tags: php, image-uploading

Form

```
<form action="product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="image" class="input3" multiple>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Product" name="submit" class="button2">
</form>
```

product.php

```
$image = $_FILES['image'];
 $i = 1 ;
 foreach ($image as $new_image)
    {
       print_r($new_image);
       echo '<br>';
       $dir_path_up = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model."/";
       $target_file = $dir_path_up . basename($new_image);
       $new_name= $dir_path_up .$i.".jpg";
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $new_name);

       $i++;
    }
```

I used above code to Rename image and upload image to specific($model) directory. All looks perfect, when upload a single image. But when I upload more than Single Image, last image only get rename and Upload. (Example : If i upload 3 image, last image get only upload and it get rename as `1.jpg`. and rest of previous images are not getting upload.)

Is some thing wrong in this?? I get Struck on this.

Comment: What does your upload form look like?

Comment: submit your full code of your view and php

Comment: <form action="product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @Abdulla I didn't mean that. Post your form's html here..

Comment: @web-nomad form html means??

Comment: See @ashwani's answer below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are uploading the images the last image will be uploaded only the reason being you are not handling it correctly. Try `print_r($_FILES)` before this to see the actual structure.

1. You need to use

   `<input type="file" name="image[]" />`
2. The sample structure you should have:

Array
(

```
[image] => Array
    (

        [name] => Array
            (

                [0] => architectural-245a.jpg

                [1] => BeaverMeadow_EN-US12190942812_1920x1200.jpg

                [2] => cool-chelsea-wallpaper-25403-26085-hd-wallpapers.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => image/jpeg
                [1] => image/jpeg
                [2] => image/jpeg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpE4FF.tmp
                [1] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpE52F.tmp
                [2] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpE54F.tmp
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 689711
                [1] => 642453
                [2] => 396336
            )

    )
```

)

Then you can handle it suitably.

Comment: In this also I'm getting last inserted image.

Comment: Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => 3-Floor-standing-LCD-AD-Display.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php8938.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 2816 ) )

Comment: are you getting all your images in the above format (The one I have provided you)?

Comment: One more thing you should use `for ` instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

First problem is with name of the `input(type= file)` field you have taken for uploading file. your form is actually uploading only one file which was selected in the end. That is why you are facing that problem.

So solve this rename it as  `image[]`

```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="file" name="image[]" class="input3" multiple> <!-- As you are uploading multiple file so u have to define name as array like =image[] -->
         <input type="submit" value="Add Product" name="submit" class="button2">
     </form> 

   <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $image = $_FILES['image'];
        $image = reArrayFiles($image);  /* use this function to create a proper $_FILES['image'] array format*/
         $i = 1 ;
         foreach ($image as $new_image)
            {
               print_r($new_image);
               echo '<br>';
               $dir_path_up = "upload";
               $target_file = $dir_path_up . basename($new_image['name']);
               $new_name= $dir_path_up .$i.".jpg"; /*if you use .jpg here then all the files will be converted into .jpg even if user uploads a txt file or other*/
               move_uploaded_file($new_image["tmp_name"], $new_name);
               $i++;
            }
    }

    function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

        $file_ary = array();
        $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
        $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
        }

        return $file_ary;
    }
    ?>
```